# Apache FOP - how to configure opensans in pdf

Tags: fonts, embed, apache-fop

I would like to embed "Open Sans" in PDF via Apache FOP; I have tried lot of different options what I ever I read it from google; however I couldn't configure this font in PDF. Could you please anyone could guide me "how to embed "Open Sans" in PDF via Apache FOP

I have referred this link aswell; but no luck

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/fonts.html

Comment: After [dowloading the ttf files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14170175/4453460) you can normally [register them in FOP's configuration](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/fonts.html#register).

Comment: When we tried to navigate these links, it looks too much. Could you please let me know whether you have any documentation or steps to follow which helps to apply the same?

Comment: I have tried this link aswell; I couldn't get what I need: https://pages.lip6.fr/Jean-Francois.Perrot/XML-Int/Session6/FOPFonts/index.html